# erlang: running "erl" I get "Fatal, could not get clock_monotonic value!, errno=22"

Tags: erlang

I have cross-compiled Erlang on a DNS-323 NAS but I get the error "Fatal, could not get clock_monotonic value!, errno=22".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Google search for "erlang errno 22" turned up several hits, of which [this one](http://somic.org/2009/04/14/compiling-erlang-on-linux-with-old-glibc/) might be relevant.